# Can a one-variable function generate a two-variable function with a certain property?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

Suppose a function $f$ of two variables is obeying
$$
f(x,\,y) = f(xy,\,1)\;.\qquad\qquad\;\qquad (1)
$$
Using $f$, we can define a function $\varphi(z)$ of one variable,
$$
\varphi(z) \equiv f(z,\,1)\;.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (2)
$$
Stated alternativaly,
$$
\mbox{for}\;\forall\;f(x,\,y)\;\mbox{obeying (1)}\,,\;\;\exists\;\varphi(z)\;:\;\;\varphi(xy)=f(x,y)\;.
$$
Now, the inverse problem:
from an arbitrary $\varphi(z)$, can we build an $f(x,y)$ satisfying (1) and linked to $\varphi$ via (2)?

Comment: I don't follow.  Condition (1) does not involve $\varphi$ at all.  Do you mean for any 1-variable function $\varphi$ does there exist a 2-variable function $f$ such that $\varphi(z) = f(z,1)$?  If so, the answer is yes:  $f(x,y)=y\varphi(x)$.

Comment: @Randall Thank you for your response. Did you really mean $y\,\varphi(x)$ or, perhaps, $\varphi(xy)\,$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, $f$ is already explicit by $f(x,y)=\varphi (xy)$.
This $f$ satisfies $f(x,y)=\varphi (xy)=f(xy,1)$.

Comment: It is not clear to me that OP means to assume that $\varphi$ satisfies the identity $\varphi(xy)=f(x,y)$ already.

Comment: Well, I read the question as "can we find $f$ satisfying (1) from $\varphi$?" The sentences before might be an explanation of background, *if I understand correctly* :)

Comment: @Ayaka Thank you for your answer, and sorry for my unclear question. I have now changed it as you suggested: from an arbitrary $\varphi(z)$, can we build an $f(x,y)$ satisfying (1) and linked to $\varphi$ via (2)?

Comment: @Randall My initial question was not clear enough. I have now fixed it. First, from an $f$ satisfying (1), we build $\varphi$. The question then is if we can, from an arbitrary $\varphi$, generate an $f$ satisfying (1).

Comment: Anyway, clarifying the question is an important step toward a solution. Please make best!